# Choosing the right $\delta$ for uniformly continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm reading a proof for the claim $g(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

It comes down to: $\forall x,y>B:\left|g(x)-g(y)\right|\le \left|x-y\right| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

The auther claims $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\varepsilon/2,1\}$

- $\delta_1$ is for the closed interval $[0,B]$ (By Cantor's theorem)
- $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ is clear from the inequality
- **What the $1$ is for?**

**Full question and proof:**
Let $f(x)$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)=1$ and $g(x) = f(x)\sin x$. Show that $g(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

**Proof:**
$g(x) = f(x)\sin x = \sin x + (f(x) -1)\sin x$.

There is $x_0$ such that for all $x>x_0$: $\left|f(x)-1\right| \le \varepsilon / 4\Rightarrow \left|(f(x)-1)\sin x \right| \le \varepsilon / 4$

$g(x)$ continuous so by Cantor's theorem it's uniformly continuous on $[0,x_0 +1]$.
Meaning, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $\delta_1$ such that for all $x,y\in [0,x_0 +1]: \left| x-y \right|< \delta_1 \Rightarrow \left| f(x)-f(y) \right| < \varepsilon$

If $x,y> x_0$ then,
$\left|g(x)-g(y)\right| \le \left|\sin x - \sin y\right| + \varepsilon/4 + \varepsilon/4 \le \left|x-y\right| + \varepsilon/2$

And the rest is clear..

Comment: It could be to avoid saying "without loss of generality", as w.l.o.g. one can take $\delta_1 < 1$ and $\epsilon < 1$. It might ensure that some simple bound holds, depends on the details. Almost surely it is not very important.

Comment: I just don't know: can you describe what is _Cantor's theorem_? Is it different from the one in set theorey?

Comment: Cantor's theorem in this context means the Heine-Cantor theorem, that is, "if $f$ is a continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous." (One may of course replace $\mathbb{R}$ by any metric space without any significant change to the proof.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of Darksonn is already pointing in the right direction.

Notice that there are two different proofs depending on whether you're working on the interval $[0,x_0+1]$ or $[x_0,\infty)$. However, for the argument of either of these to work, both $x$ and $y$ have to lie within the same interval. This you can accomplish by ensuring that $| x - y | < 1$, and hence the additional requirement that $\delta \le 1$.

Comment: Got it. But if we choose $[0,x_0],(x_0,\infty)$ we can get away from it. Right?

Comment: @Elimination Not really. Requiring $\delta < \delta_1$ where $\delta_1$ is given by Heine-Cantor does the job when both $x$ and $y$ are "small". Requiring $\delta < \varepsilon/2$ does the job when both $x$ and $y$ are "large". Requiring $\delta < 1$ makes it so we do not wind up with $x$ being "small" when $y$ is "large" or vice versa.

Comment: But how $1$ was chosen? And how do we know that it does work for $\left|x-y\right|<1$? It doesn't mentioned in the proof.

Comment: The $1$ comes from the fact that the two intervals have an overlap of length one. Thus if $x,y$ are less than distance one separated, then there is at least one of the two intervals that contains both. Then you can use the estimate corresponding to that interval. You could have chosen the overlap to be any $\eta > 0$ and then choose $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\varepsilon/2,\eta)$.

Answer (score 1):

A $1$ in a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof is almost always from somewhere in the proof where the author said

I would like this value (ex. $|x+1|$) to never be larger than $1$, so I can prove this much easier, and then you can assume it's not for the rest of the proof. Then at the end you have to deal with the case of it being larger than $1$ and you simply bound the $\delta$ value by $1$ to make sure that when this $|x+1|$ value is larger than $1$, the value of $\delta$ still works.

Comment: Can you refer my update and explain where the $1$ comes in handy for this specific case? I don't understand it completly.

Comment: I'm not sure where it comes from in this case, I haven't worked alot with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs but I have seen a few where it was used the way I descriped, so I assumed it was the same here..